# Redirigir tráfico en iptables guardando la ip de origen

Tags: iptables

Buenas, quiero que todo el tráfico que llegue al puerto 80 sea redirigido al 5050 pero que en el 5050 me llegue con la ip de origen que llegó al puerto 80, no la de mi máquina. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Seria bueno ver las reglas actuales o la parte que afecta a este tema, pero por lo que comentas asumo que luego de redireccionar en la cadena prerouting een algun punto el paquete esta pasando por un MASQUERADE, deberia cambiarlo por un ACCEPT, si esto no funciona seria buejn oque agregues el codigo para poder verlo mejor

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de leer algo con `iptables` que utiliza algo por el estilo.

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5050
```

Entonces podrías hacer algo como esto para probarlo.

```
$ nc -l 5050 > datos & # Para captar todo lo que llegue al puerto 5050 y guardarlo en un archivo.
```

Luego te tratas de conectar a esa tu IP pública, por ejemplo, con `curl` y el header `X-Forwarded-For`

```
$ curl <ip publica>:<puerto>/sub1/sub2/page.page --header "X-Forwarded-For: <ip de origen>"
```

Y el contenido del archivo "datos" tendría que tener algo semejante a esto.

```
GET /sub1/sub2/page.page HTTP/1.1
Host : <ip del host>
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
X-Forwarded-For: <ip de origen>
```